# Odd Vector Product Question

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces, mathematical-physics

Here is a question that has me stumped:

Use the geometric definition to find: $2 {\bf i} × ({\bf i}+{\bf j})$

Student solution manual says: By the definition of cross product, $2 {\bf i} × ({\bf i}+{\bf j})$
 is in the direction of ${\bf k}$. The magnitude of it equals to the area of the parallelogram which is:
$$
||2{\bf i}||·||{\bf i}+{\bf j}||\sin(\pi/4) = 2\sqrt2·(\sqrt2/2)=2
$$
So $2{\bf i} × ({\bf i}+{\bf j}) =2{\bf k}$

I understand to use the geometric definition which is the formula $||v||·||w||\sin(\theta)·n$ where $\sin(\theta)$ is the angle between the vectors $v$ and $w$. The problem is why the $({\bf i}+{\bf j})$ is a rotation of $45$ degrees between the $x$ and $y$ axis.

Comment: Just realized that (i+j) is the vector that has the coefficient of 1i and 1j. Thus creating a vector that projects into quadrant 1 that forms a right triangle with a sin(theta) of 45 degrees or pi/4. Therefore: ||2i||=2, ||i+j||=sqrt(1^2+1^2)=sqrt(2). Then 2*sqrt(2)*sin(pi/4)=2

Comment: You can answer your own question!

Answer (score 0):

Using the linearity of the cross product and the cross products of the canonical basis vectors, one can simply compute
$$
2{\bf i}×({\bf i}+{\bf j})=2{\bf i}×{\bf i}+2{\bf i}×{\bf j}=0+2{\bf k}
$$

---

For any two vectors $v$, $w$ of equal length, $v+w$, or in general $\|w\|·v+\|v\|·w$, -- if not zero -- is a vector in the direction of the angle bisector between $v$ and $w$.

Since the angle between the unit vectors ${\bf i}$ and ${\bf j}$ is $90°$, the bisected angle is $45°$ between ${\bf i}$ and ${\bf i}+{\bf j}$ resp. ${\bf i}+{\bf j}$ and ${\bf j}$.